# Rsync not modifying files on destination

Tags: rsync

I'm trying to accomplish a very simple goal. I'm just simply trying to sync two directories together and not having much success. I'm using the following command

`rsync -avR /path/to/source/folder /path/to/destination/folder`

It shows a lot of stuff in the output when I run this command (no errors), but when I go to check a file from the destination folder that I've changed in the source, the contents are still old.

Any ideas why this may be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you use the `-R` (`--relative`) option the source directory hierarchy would be written to `/path/to/destination/folder/path/to/source/folder`.

To make `/path/to/destination/folder` a copy of `/path/to/source/folder`, use

```
rsync -av /path/to/source/folder/ /path/to/destination/folder
```

Note that I removed the `-R` option and that I also added a `/` to the end of the source path.  Without the `/` at the end of the source path, the source directory would have been copied as `/path/to/destination/folder/folder`.

Add `--delete` to the command if you wish to *remove files not existing in the source path*. (When experimenting, always use copies of data, or data that is properly backed up!)